# How can I check an URL is a video URL

Tags: android, url

I want to create a project that can see online videos without downloading with ExoPlayer.

ExoPlayer supports many formats [like these](https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html)
I want to supoort all these formats(Progressive container formats).
I searched and I couldn't find anything

I want to check whether the user Entered URL is a supported URL or not.Any help would be appreciate .

I'm using ExoPlayer.You can use ExoPlayer try-catch

I tried these codes but not working because some URLs are HTTPS or some URI,s includes some characters after the format

```
String URL = et_url.getText().toString();
    if(URL.matches("http://[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+.[a-z]/[a-zA-Z0-9._-].mp4"))
    {

    }
    else if (URL.matches("http://[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+.[a-z]/[a-zA-Z0-9._-].mkv"))
    {

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you can do a http HEAD request on the resource, and then check the content-type. url itself won't tell you much if a given resource is a video or not.

Comment: viz,Can you help me more?

Answer (score 5):

You could "probably" check if a URL locates a video resource by the trailing file extension regex you are trying to compose.

But theoretically, [the URL representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) itself won't tell you if a given resource on the network that a URL(or more broadly, a URI) is pointing to is a video or not. The URL can be anything like `http://can_you_tell_this_is_a_video` and still locate a video.

Also, it's hard/impossible to tell if a video is actually "playable" by the player(supported encoding, file format, etc.), even though you knew that that's a video resource. The simpler way to solve the problem would be to just try feeding the player with whatever URL you receive from the user. And if the player says it's not playable, then proceed with the next step.

On the other hand, if you just need to identify if a URL is locating is a video resource, then the straightforward way is to do [a HTTP HEAD request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) at the URL with a HTTP client, and check [the Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to see if the resource is among [the common video MIME types](http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/).

To give an example, if you do a HEAD request on `https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`(you can test it [here](https://reqbin.com/)), the HTTP response will look like below(the server needs to support HEAD requests and provide the correct content-type header, normally they should):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1055736
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Wed, 22 May 2019 20:51:28 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 17:43:54 GMT
Server: Apache
```

With this response, now you can check the `Content-Type` header value - as you can see, in this example the media type of the resource is `video/mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can solve this using this way -**

```
 String fileType = getFileTypeFromURL("https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
        if(fileType.equals("video")){
            // Do your task here
        }



private String getFileTypeFromURL(String url){
        String[] splitedArray = url.split("\\.");
        String lastValueOfArray = splitedArray[splitedArray.length-1];
        if(lastValueOfArray.equals("mp4") || lastValueOfArray.equals("flv") || lastValueOfArray.equals("m4a") || lastValueOfArray.equals("3gp") || lastValueOfArray.equals("mkv")){
            return "video";
        }else if(lastValueOfArray.equals("mp3") || lastValueOfArray.equals("ogg")){
            return "audio";
        }else if(lastValueOfArray.equals("jpg") || lastValueOfArray.equals("png") || lastValueOfArray.equals("gif")){
            return "photo";
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

You can check this by using headers information -

```
URL obj = new URL(VIDEO_URL);
URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();

//Get all headers
Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                 " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}

//get header by 'key'
String content_type = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
```

Comment: `http://randomtestlinkforalaminhaha.com` might be a valid video url, but your approach won't detect that.

Comment: You should consider capital cases in your first example (.MP4)
`String lastValueOfArray = splitedArray[splitedArray.length-1].toLowerCase();`